# Mapping excel to XML - Problem importing XML-fields

Tags: excel, xml

I seem to have a problem with mapping XML parts to an existing exceltable.

I have a sample XML file provided from the Swedish tax authority as XML-schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Skatteverket xmlns="http://xmls.skatteverket.se/se/skatteverket/ai/instans/infoForBeskattning/4.0"
xmlns:gm="http://xmls.skatteverket.se/se/skatteverket/ai/gemensamt/infoForBeskattning/4.0"
xmlns:ku="http://xmls.skatteverket.se/se/skatteverket/ai/komponent/infoForBeskattning/4.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" omrade="Kontrolluppgifter"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmls.skatteverket.se/se/skatteverket/ai/instans/infoForBeskattning/4.0
http://xmls.skatteverket.se/se/skatteverket/ai/kontrolluppgift/instans/Kontrolluppgifter_4.0.xsd ">
<ku:Avsandare>
    <ku:Programnamn>KUfilsprogrammet</ku:Programnamn>
        <ku:Organisationsnummer>162234567895</ku:Organisationsnummer>
    <ku:TekniskKontaktperson>
        <ku:Namn>Bo Ek</ku:Namn>
        <ku:Telefon>+46881234567</ku:Telefon>
        <ku:Epostadress>bo.ek@elbolagetab.se</ku:Epostadress>
        <ku:Utdelningsadress1>Strömgatan 11</ku:Utdelningsadress1>
        <ku:Postnummer>62145</ku:Postnummer>
        <ku:Postort>Strömby</ku:Postort>
    </ku:TekniskKontaktperson>
    <ku:Skapad>2015-06-07T21:32:52</ku:Skapad>
</ku:Avsandare>
<ku:Blankettgemensamt>
    <ku:Uppgiftslamnare>
        <ku:UppgiftslamnarePersOrgnr>165599990602</ku:UppgiftslamnarePersOrgnr>
        <ku:Kontaktperson>
            <ku:Namn>John Ström</ku:Namn>
            <ku:Telefon>+46812345678</ku:Telefon>
            <ku:Epostadress>siv.strom@elbolagetab.se</ku:Epostadress>
            <ku:Sakomrade>Förnybar el</ku:Sakomrade>
        </ku:Kontaktperson>
    </ku:Uppgiftslamnare>
</ku:Blankettgemensamt>
<!-- Kontrolluppgift 1 -->
<ku:Blankett nummer="2350">
    <ku:Arendeinformation>
        <ku:Arendeagare>165599990602</ku:Arendeagare>
        <ku:Period>2018</ku:Period>
    </ku:Arendeinformation>
    <ku:Blankettinnehall>
        <ku:KU66>
            <ku:UppgiftslamnareKU66>
                <ku:UppgiftslamnarId faltkod="201">165599990602</ku:UppgiftslamnarId>
                <ku:NamnUppgiftslamnare faltkod="202">Sonjas elhandel</ku:NamnUppgiftslamnare>
            </ku:UppgiftslamnareKU66>
            <ku:Inkomstar faltkod="203">2018</ku:Inkomstar>
            <ku:KWhMatatsIn faltkod="270">3622</ku:KWhMatatsIn>
            <ku:KWhTagitsUt faltkod="271">4822</ku:KWhTagitsUt>
            <ku:AnlaggningsID faltkod="272">735999123456789012</ku:AnlaggningsID>
            <ku:AndelIAnslPunkt faltkod="273">12.5</ku:AndelIAnslPunkt>
            <ku:Specifikationsnummer faltkod="570">128</ku:Specifikationsnummer>
            <ku:InkomsttagareKU66>
                <ku:Inkomsttagare faltkod="215">193804139149</ku:Inkomsttagare>
            </ku:InkomsttagareKU66>
        </ku:KU66>
    </ku:Blankettinnehall>
</ku:Blankett>
</Skatteverket>
```

When using Excel, Developer tab -> XML -> Source and adding the file I don't seem to get the XML parts inside the tag

```
<ku:Blankettinnahall>
```

Any reason why Excel would skip these XML parts?

Here is some sample exceltable data that I would like to map to those XML-fields:

```
AnlaggningsID   Inkomsttagare   Inkomstar   KWhMatatsIn KWhTagitsUt AndelIAnslPunkt Specifikationsnummer
526009875445385000  190101019999    2018    50078,0 88462,0     1
258655985101244000  190201019999    2018    75,0    4615,0      2
112855269388863000  190301019999    2018    16687,0 19870,0 42  3
364615095294089000  190401019999    2018    16687,0 19870,0 58  4
534980084130649000  190501019999    2018    174,0   7009,0      5
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your missing the actual data itself...the top half is the description of the sender and details. And later is data section (Blankettinnehall)

So on your excel I would expect rows with columns for each header/ sender details. This may be whats missing.

You can see this if you take a sample file from them and view it in Excel.

I struggled with KU52 last year ended up doing a C# application to generate the XML file.